# Mac's displaying different ID's in DHCP?

Tags: active-directory, dhcp, mac

We have a number of Mac users on our domain; many of these machines have been brought in from other organisations (we merged with another).

They are binding to the domain correctly, and showing up on Active Directory with the naming convention we have chosen (Eg COMP0015).

However, in DHCP they are displaying with different ID (e.g AdministratorMac3).

Where is the ID on a mac that broadcasts this other name? I cannot for the life of me find where DHCP is getting these ID's from..

Comment: dhcp is only working with MAC and ip addresses. That hostname comes from other protocol.

Comment: A DHCP client can submit an hostname in the request. A DHCP server can send an hostname in a reply (it may or may not be the same). It's part of DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

On MAC try:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open Network.
3. Click on Ethernet on the left to to highlight it.
4. Click Advanced at the lower right
5. Click the TCP/IP tab Locate the DHCP
6. Client ID area and type in the name you want, +MacBook Pro+, for
   example
7. Click OK, then click Apply

Comment: So, bizzarely, this has had a strange effect. Adding the correct naming convention to the Client ID and waited for the lease to renew; the new machine name doesn't show up in the DHCP lease, but the old name si now missing. User still has full network access....?